# Show that for any two real numbers $x, y \in [0,1]$, there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{N}^0$, $a,b \leq 18$ not both equal to $0$ such that $|ax-by|<1/9.$

Tags: real-numbers, absolute-value, natural-numbers

This is a problem coming from a math gazette. I have tried to approach this problem by dividing the interval $[0,1]$ into intervals $\left[0, \frac{1}{9}\right], \left[\frac{1}{9}, \frac{2}{9}\right], \ldots , \left[\frac{8}{9}, 1\right]$ and seeing where $x$ and $y$ could be and choosing $a$ and $b$ accordingly, but I didn't end up with anything close to a solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would start by looking at the cases where $b$ (or $a$) equals $0$, i.e. when we can find $a$ such that $\vert ax\vert < 1/9$.

Comment: Is your $\mathbb N$ containing $0$? If not, as stated the problem is not true: take $x=0$ and $y=1$.

Comment: It is containing 0

Comment: I've never seen $\mathbb N\cup \{0\}$ written as $\mathbb N^0$.  But I have seen $\mathbb N$ defined to include $0$ frequently.  Frankly I think the original title was utterly acceptable.  The "both not equal to $0$" makes it very clear that $0$ is considered a natural number.